# Action sheet entries limited to 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

A multi-selection actionsheet within a select, limits entries to 5 elements. Why?
I'm testing with the documentation code example from ion-select.
Only the first 5 options are considered.

It works fine for single selection (interface "popover") but fails with multiple selection multi="true", either with interface "popover" or "action-sheet"

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Toppings</ion-label>
    <ion-select multiple="true" cancelText="Nah" okText="Okay!">
      <ion-select-option value="bacon">Bacon</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="olives">Black Olives</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="xcheese">Extra Cheese</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="peppers">Green Peppers</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="onions">Onions</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="pineapple">Pineapple</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="sausage">Sausage</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="Spinach">Spinach</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I expected to see 10 entries, in this example

Comment: I dont think so it has any limit of 5. You can also look doc example.  https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: May be some css code stops it. pls check.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. During my investigations I saw no limit stated anywhere, but the reality is I'm facing it. I will investigate CSS limitations

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: Not yet. Investigated css using chrome inspect but no success. Tried to look for any maximum-height definition, but didn't found. Don't know how to test imposing a new maximum-height (don't even know if this test makes sense). Any suggestions? Thank you for your concern